# How to add fields to Django Forms with a decorator

Tags: python, django, forms, decorator

I need to add a ChoiceField to a number of different forms, and the choices come from a class attribute on each form. Each form has its own set of other fields too.

I can't put the field in a base class because that class would not have the choices attribute, so I thought I could use a decorator to add the field onto each subclass.

However, even though the decorator adds the field to the form class, it doesn't get included when the form is rendered in a template. There's some metaclass black magic I'm missing.

How can a decorator add a field to a form?

Comment: Use a form factory and dynamically generate the form class using `type()`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to replace the forms' constructor in the decorator like so:

```
def form_with_captcha(orig_form, theme=None):
    if hasattr(orig_form, "captcha"):
        raise ValueError("form already has a field captcha!")
    orig_form.__orig__init__ = orig_form.__init__

    def new_init(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.__orig__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields["captcha"] = self.captcha

    orig_form.__init__ = new_init
    orig_form.captcha = ReCaptchaField(attrs={"theme": theme or "white"})
    return orig_form
```